# If statement on one line including html inside it

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code:

```
        <th class="
            @if( @Request.QueryString["desc"].AsBool() ){ @:table-desc }
            @if( @Request.QueryString["desc"].AsBool() ){ @:table-desc }
        " width="100%" @Html.SortTableClickEvent(@Request.Path, "Name", Convert.ToBoolean(@Request.QueryString["desc"]))>
            Name
        </th>
```

It doesn't like the @if statement all being on one line, the "@:table-desc" thinks that the closing bracket "}" is part of the html.

Any ideas how to get around this?

```
Parser Error Message: The if block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.
```

Comment: Just wrapping the HTML in `<text></text>` should work, rather than the `@:` shorthand. Is that not acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

You want to print a string, so:

```
@if( @Request.QueryString["desc"].AsBool() ){ @":table-desc" }
```

You can also stick it in a variable:

```
@{
    var sortClass = Request.QueryString["desc"].AsBool() 
        ? "table-desc" 
        : "table-asc";
}

<th class="@sortClass">
```

Comment: That's much neater.. but not a good solution for my context (although you would not have known that when answering..) thanks though, learnt something new!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<th class="@Request.QueryString["desc"].AsBool()?table-desc:table-desc".....
```

Or use something like below which i have implemented in my application

```
<th class="@if (Request.QueryString["desc"].AsBool())
             {<text>trueclass</text>}
            else       
            {text>falseclass</text>}" >
```

Comment: Cool, I like it... but what if the else statement is empty.. so if it is desc, then output "table-desc, otherwise output nothing... if I put an empty string in it does squigglywigglies

Comment: What if I want to output nothing if it is false... something like this but this doesn't work: <th class="@Request.QueryString["desc"].AsBool()?table-desc:

Comment: cant u give any class which is present or not present in your stylesheet

Comment: Hah, well I guess I could.